# Where is the rerefence documentation for AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, documentation, automapper

I look for the documentation for AutoMapper for C#. The only thing I have found is [this wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki), but that is both incomplete and not an actual per-function documentation. It is difficult to find documentation for a specific function.

Specifically I search for the difference between `DynamicMap(sourceValue, sourceType, destinationType)` and `Map(sourceValue, sourceType, destinationType)`.
I have found some unofficial Q&A posts by googleing, but those were not really explanatory, and especially they were not "official documentation".

Comment: The official documentation are the xml code comments and the wiki.

Comment: Hmm, are there any ways to see these XML comments in Visual Studio when just referring the DLLs?

Comment: Yes, as long as the XML doc file is alongside the DLL you referenced. If you're using NuGet this is all done automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is simple - there is no actual per-function documentation for AutoMapper. It is not commercial product. It's just library shared by [Jimmy Bogard](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/01/23/automapper-the-object-object-mapper/) and you can use it as is (without detailed official documentation).

First thing to note, is that source code of AutoMapper has good xml comments you can rely on:

```
/// <summary>
/// Execute a mapping from the source object to a new destination object
/// with explicit <see cref="System.Type"/> objects
/// </summary>
static object Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType)

/// <summary>
/// Create a map between the <paramref name="sourceType"/> and
/// <paramref name="destinationType"/> types and execute the map.
/// Use this method when the source and destination types are
/// not known until runtime.
/// </summary>
static object DynamicMap(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
```

As it says, you should use `DynamicMap` when source and destinations types are not known until runtime. Difference between these types of mapping is not clear when you are using non-generic version of methods. But usually we use generic methods. E.g. creating map looks like:

```
// here you can write type names, because you know them
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
```

After map was created you can execute this mapping

```
Source source = new Source { Id = 42, Name = "Bob" };
Destination destination = Mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
```

But you can't use same code for anonymous types. E.g. you have following object:

```
var source = new { Id = 13, Name = "Joe" };
```

You can't use generic parametrized mapping creation for this type, because you don't know it's name.

```
Mapper.CrateMap</*What goes here?*/, Destination>();
```

That's why dynamic mapping was introduced. It does both things - creates map AND executes it:

```
var source = new { Id = 13, Name = "Joe" };
Destination destincation = Mapper.DynamicMap<Destination>(source);
```

With your non-generic methods you can simply use `source.GetType()` to get type of source object, so it's not problem.

One more note - you can use Jimmy's blog as source of information about AutoMapper features. For example, he describes dynamic mapping [here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/04/15/automapper-feature-interfaces-and-dynamic-mapping/).